# How can I run an HTML/CSS/Javascript site on AWS Lambda/API Gateway without using AWS Amplify?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, web, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Sorry if this is a silly question since I know that AWS has an article on how to do this with AWS Amplify: [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)

But I want to do this work with AWS SAM and it seems AWS SAM doesn't support many services including AWS Amplify.

If someone can just point me in the right direction or let me know that it is not possible, I'd appreciate it.

I can't get the JavaScript part to work with API Gateway

Comment: SAM existed before Amplify, so it's pretty easy to find tutorials out there that setup websites with SAM without using Amplify. For example: https://izifortune.com/serverless-website-sam-aws/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with one of two ways described below.

#### First: AWS S3 Website Hosting

NOTE: You can't configure custom domain with this scenario and below instruction is simplified. Visit documentation page for more details.

Create AWS S3 bucket, upload HTML, CSS and JS sources and enabled *Static Website Hosting* in S3 bucket's *Properties*.

Using AWS Console:

1. Open your S3 Bucket
2. Navigate to Bucket **Properties**
3. Under **Static website hosting** choose **Edit**
4. In **Index document** enter file name of index document, typically `index.html`.
5. *(Optional, more info in documentation)* You can provide custom document for 4XX class errors
6. **Save changes**
7. Under **Static website hosting** there will be your website endpoint.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EnableWebsiteHosting.html

#### Second: AWS S3 + CloudFront

NOTE: You can have custom domain with this scenario.

There are couple of options to consider, so read the details in AWS documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/